# What does everyone use for local Shopware development specifically when developing full sites?

Tags: docker, installation, localhost, shopware, shopware6

I've found different ways to setup a local development environment for Shopware 6 but have so far only tried Dockware. The dev image has some tools which I find amazing like watch-admin and watch-storefront, but it should be used for plugin development and not full site. What is the "best" local Shopware 6 dev environment setup?

Could you include your docker-compose.yml when you use one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My vote goes to: [ddev](https://github.com/drud/ddev). Out of the box support of SW5/6, very good support (through discord or here on SO), [good docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and very high customization.
I've been using it for months now on Windows 10 + WSL and it's been an absolute breeze to work with!

Answer (score 3):

Dockware is working fine to me for Plugin dev and "full site". You can create your own image from templates: https://github.com/dockware/dockware/tree/master/.dist/versions/master/dev/6.4.12.0

Comment: We even use it for CI/CD with github actions, easily can test store plugins against multiple shopware versions, with an easy config, and also test and validating full site projects

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't agree more with https://stackoverflow.com/users/3329355/jim. Using ddev on Ubuntu for Shopware 5 and 6.

This is my ddev/config.yaml for a simple Shopware 6 project:

```
name: my-project
type: shopware6
docroot: public
php_version: "8.0"
webserver_type: apache-fpm
router_http_port: "80"
router_https_port: "443"
xdebug_enabled: false
additional_hostnames: []
additional_fqdns: []
mariadb_version: ""
mysql_version: "8.0"
use_dns_when_possible: true
composer_version: ""
web_environment:
 - APP_URL=http://${DDEV_SITENAME}.ddev.site
 - COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1
```

Should you want to use the storefront and/or admin watcher, add a file docker-compose.watcher.yaml to your .ddev directory:

```
version: "3.6"

services:
    web:
        expose:
            # Storefront Hot Proxy Ports
            - 9997
            - 9998
            - 9999
        environment:
            # Shopware Administration Watch Host
            - HOST=0.0.0.0
            # Shopware Administration Watch Port
            - PORT=9997
            # Expose APP_URL to administration watcher
            - APP_URL=http://${DDEV_SITENAME}.ddev.site
            - HTTP_EXPOSE=${DDEV_ROUTER_HTTP_PORT}:80,${DDEV_MAILHOG_PORT}:8025,9999:9999,9998:9998,9997:9997
            - HTTPS_EXPOSE=${DDEV_ROUTER_HTTPS_PORT}:80,${DDEV_MAILHOG_HTTPS_PORT}:8025,8899:9999,8888:9998,8887:9997
```

Comment: I've created the local environment using ddev and so far it's amazing performance wise. I can't seem to get the `watch-administraction.sh` script working tho. It uses port 8080 while your script seems to use `9997`, `9998` or `9999`? Can I just change these ports and run `bin/watch-administration.sh` from inside the `ddev ssh` command?

Comment: Nevermind! It already works. I had a typo in my docker-compose file.

Comment: Hey @Alphaegen do you mind sharing, what kind of typo you did? I can't get the config to work in my ddev

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of flailing around we eventually used the shopware [production repository](https://github.com/shopware/production) as a template, we forked it.  It seems to me that the development repository is focussed on plugin development only, not full projects.  The watch admin and watch storefront features you mentioned exist on the production repository, they are shell scripts in the bin folder.  We had to modify the images to get them into a workable state for us in a few ways:

1. there were a few changes we needed to make for webpack watching and compiling to work:

   1. modify the docker compose template to listen to the ports webpack expected (8080/9998), we had to map them to different ports within docker so they wouldn't clash with webpack (e.g. 8080 -> docker -> 8081)
   2. add an nginx config to proxy those requests to webpack again e.g. (8081 -> nginx -> 8080)
   3. use nginx to reset the Upgrade and Connection headers for websocket requests
2. add a bunch of utilities to make working in the image easier (bash, npm, that sort of thing)
3. I had to install composer [programmatically](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-to-install-composer-programmatically.md) as part of the build
4. our optional project-specific stuff (we wanted rabbit for queues, we created docker images for working the queue and the task scheduler)

We've not been working with this setup for long, but we are happy with it so far: we wanted to have development and production setups using the same repo, and minimally different docker setups, and this approach ticks all those boxes.  I have to say we weren't aware of dockware at the point of doing all this, but there are some advantages of doing things in house I guess.